# I need to declare a variable in oracle view

Tags: oracle

Basically I have a view  which is having below query as a part of view .

```
SELECT site_id ch_site_id 
  FROM bfg_router_pi_details 
 WHERE last_modified_date > (SELECT MAX (last_time_stamp) 
                               FROM saa_bfg_feed_ctl)
```

Now in this query bfg_router_pi_details  is a view in  another  database and saa_bfg_feed_ctl  is a table in same database from we are firing this query.

Now when This query is fired like above using inner query in where clause, it takes 2 hours to finish as it is going over the db link. however if i replace the inner query with the actual date value it takes 2 minutes. so I am trying to see if there is any way that I can define a variable in view and assign the last time stamp value to that variable and then replace that variable in the  where clause of the query so that execution become s faster. hope you understood the problem in hand.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because Oracle is choosing the remote site as the driving site for the query. Try this hint to tell it to run the query from the local site:

```
SELECT /*+DRIVING_SITE(saa_bfg_feed_ctl) */
       site_id ch_site_id 
FROM bfg_router_pi_details 
WHERE last_modified_date > (SELECT MAX (last_time_stamp) 
                           FROM saa_bfg_feed_ctl)
```

I'm not 100% sure on this off the top of my head - if you post a plan for your query might be able to help further.

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways how to do it but surely all of them require plsql programming. The most simple one is to create a package where a variable with your MAX is assigned before you make the query to the view.
so the view will look like

```
begin
 SELECT MAX (last_time_stamp) 
 into your_package.your_variable
 FROM saa_bfg_feed_ctl
end;
```

may be you need no_data_found but it's not my cup of tea

```
SELECT site_id ch_site_id 
  FROM bfg_router_pi_details 
 WHERE last_modified_date > your_package.your_variable
```

You could use user plsql context by the same way so please consider about it the original documentation - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/app_context.htm

Comment: +1 But your example incorrectly implies it is possible to directly reference a package variable in a SQL statement.  You will need to write a function to retrieve the value.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. That's why I mentioned contexts as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but it's no 1 in google search results and I've never used a package
So I worked out a different approach using CTE:

```
with my_variable as (SELECT MAX (last_time_stamp) as val
                           FROM saa_bfg_feed_ctl)

SELECT /*+DRIVING_SITE(saa_bfg_feed_ctl) */
       site_id ch_site_id 
FROM bfg_router_pi_details 
left join my_variable on val = val

WHERE last_modified_date > val
```